# help in implementing show details view

Tags: spring-mvc, mapping

hi
Trying to build my own spring application,I made a page to input name and age.Clicking on Submit button should take me to another page that displays the user input.I decided not to use any database.As the first step ,I decided to create a controller with a method to show the form view.After I get this right,I would implement the other methods..

```
package personinfo.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import personinfo.form.PersonInfo;

@Controller
public class PersonInfoController {  
@RequestMapping(value ="/addPerson" )
public ModelAndView showAddPersonForm(){
    return new ModelAndView("addperson", "personInfoEntries", new PersonInfo());
}

@RequestMapping(value ="/addPerson" ,method =RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPersonInfo(@ModelAttribute("person")PersonInfo perInfo){
        String name = perInfo.getName();
        int age =  perInfo.getAge();
        System.out.println("Name:" + name +"Age:"+ age);
        return "showperson";//how to pass name and age
    }
...
}
```

form backing object is  personinfo.form.PersonInfo class

```
package personinfo.form;

public class PersonInfo {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public PersonInfo(){
    }

    public PersonInfo(String name,int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

/WEB-INF/jsp/addperson.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add Person</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Add Person</h2>
<form:form action="addPerson.html" commandName="personInfoEntries">
<table>
<tr>
 <td>
 <form:label path="name">Name</form:label> 
 </td>
 <td>
 <form:input path="name"/>
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>
 <form:label path="age">Age</form:label> 
 </td>
 <td>
 <form:input path="age"/>
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td colspan="2">
 <input type="submit" value="Add Person"/>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

the perinfo/WebContent/index.jsp is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>index</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:forward page="addPerson.html"></jsp:forward>
</body>
</html>
```

/perinfo/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>personinfo</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

       <servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

finally the /perinfo/WebContent/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation=
 "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
      <mvc:annotation-driven/>
      <context:annotation-config />

 <context:component-scan base-package="personinfo.controller" />

 <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
     p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
        p:suffix=".jsp">

   <property name="contentType" value="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 </bean>
</beans>
```

As chris pointed out,I added the @Controller to controller class and  to the servlet.xml .
Now I am able to see the form.When I click on the submit button ,the showperson.jsp is displayed.So far so good.

When the addPersonInfo() method in PersonInfoController is executed I would like to pass the name and age values to showperson.jsp .How can I do this? I am returning a 'showperson' view name string.How can I add the arguments to it?And I couldn't work out how to implement a corresponding method to which this viewname is to be mapped.

Can someone please show me?Or do I need to modify the return types of  addPersonInfo() method.

Please help.

thanks,

mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your follow-up question,

> When the addPersonInfo() method in
>   PersonInfoController is executed I
>   would like to pass the name and age
>   values to showperson.jsp .How can I do
>   this? I am returning a 'showperson'
>   view name string.How can I add the
>   arguments to it?And I couldn't work
>   out how to implement a corresponding
>   method to which this viewname is to be
>   mapped.

You need to add the name and age values to the model and pass that to the view. You do it inside addPerson().

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/addPerson" ,method =RequestMethod.POST)
public String addPersonInfo(@ModelAttribute("person") PersonInfo perInfo, Model model) {
        String name = perInfo.getName();
        int age =  perInfo.getAge();

        // Add name reference to Model
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        // Add age reference to Model
        model.addAttribute("age", age);

        return "showperson";
}
```

Then in your JSP page, you should at least have something like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 
<h1>Person</h1><table>
<p>name: ${id} </p>
<p>age: ${id} </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Check my other tutorials on the link I provided. There's plenty of examples like that

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read this tutorial I wrote 
[Spring Security 3 - MVC Integration Tutorial (Part 1)](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-integration.html)
so that you can compare what items you're missing with your application.

Just by glancing at your code:

```
public class PersonInfoController {  
 @RequestMapping(value ="/addPerson" )
 public String showAddPersonForm(){
  System.out.println("showing AddPersonForm");
  return "addperson";
 }
...
}
```

I notice you're missing:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/mycustommapping")
```

Normally I would write your code like this:

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/main")    
    public class PersonInfoController {  
     @RequestMapping(value ="/addPerson" )
     public String showAddPersonForm(){
      System.out.println("showing AddPersonForm");
      return "addperson";
     }
    ...
    }
```

So now the URL should be /main/addPerson

Also in your dispatcher-servlet.xml, you don't have a

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

Comment: I have updated the code and xml ..can you help me with the next step?I am trying to implement a details view..